# Harmonic function reflection

Tags: harmonic-functions, reflection

I'm  learning some harmonic function theory by reviewing some problems. I came across two:
1) Prove that a *real* harmonic function $u$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(x, 0) = 0$ for all
x ∈ $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ satisfies that $u(x,−y) = −u(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
What I tried to use is Liouville's theorem applied to the function $f(x,y)= u(x, y)+ u(x, -y)$ which eventually would be zero but I realized that the problems doesn't tell me anything about boundedness of the function.

2) A similar problem to 1) but in $\mathbb{R}^2$ only difference is that instead of having harmonicity on the whole space I'm constrained to work on the open disk of radius $a$ centered at the origin. Same condition $u(x, 0) = 0$ for all
x ∈ $\mathbb{R}$. This should result i also having $u(x,−y) = −u(x,y)$.
In this case I also tried to use $f(x,y)= u(x, y)+ u(x, -y)$ but instead I think uniqueness of the solution of Laplace's equation could be used... any help?

Comment: By "unicity" do you mean uniqueness? Could the explicit solutions of Laplace's equation be used? They are either exponential, trig or hyperbolic. You would need to show that the solutions are antisymmetric in that one variable. For example a function like sin(x)cos(y) works.  Can you show you get something similar for every solution.  Maybe start problem 1 in $R^2$.

Comment: I corrected unicity for uniqueness, sorry about that. Uhm, this reminds me of a physicist's approach, which is ok. I also do remember the solutions are combinations of those functions. The boundary condition will let me discard some solutions. However, this is heuristic since the general solution will have to be a Fourier-like sum. Separation of variables seem to be limited to a certain class of boundary conditions and also on the geometry of the domain (second case is spherical). Also, I think those are not the only functions to satisfy the equation, it's for certain geometries, I think.

Comment: I think those are it for Cartesian coordinates, although I can't guarantee it.  Dan's answer below is excellent, and saves trolling through cases.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get the result. You could for example see that your $f$ is harmonic, and satisfies $D^\alpha f(x,0) = 0$ for all multi-indices $\alpha$, which yields the result since harmonic functions are analytic. That works the same in both situations, by the way. My preferred way is to use

$$v(x,y) = \begin{cases}\;\; u(x,y) &, y \geqslant 0\\ -u(x,-y) &, y < 0. \end{cases}$$

$v$ is a continuous function that has the mean value property, hence harmonic. Since $u$ and $v$ coincide on a non-empty open set, and their domain is connected, we deduce $v \equiv u$. This also works for both situations.

For the second situation only: Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$. On a disk, every real-valued harmonic function is the imaginary part of a holomorphic function, say $u(z) = \operatorname{Im} f(z)$. Since $f$ is real-valued on $\mathbb{R} \cap D_a(0)$, we have

$$f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$$

for all $z \in D_a(0)$ by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions, and that implies

$$u(x,-y) = \operatorname{Im} f(x-iy) = - \operatorname{Im} f(x+iy) = -u(x,y).$$

Since the second situation was singled out, I suspect it was intended to write $u$ as the imaginary (or perhaps real) part of a holomorphic function, but the reflection principle works fine in both situations, and more generally, on every domain that is symmetric with respect to the reflection $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I haven't taken a rigurous course on complex analysis. I do know some facts like every real-valued harmonic function is the imaginary part of a holomorphic function but not much beyond it, particularly in what geometries I can apply this. I just googled the identity theorem and it seems strong. I don't think I was supposed to use it. Do you know how to work this out with only real variables? In any case thank you very much!

Comment: With only real variables, you can do it just like the other. You can find that all derivatives of $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + u(x,-y)$ vanish on the real axis (for $\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^n}$ that follows directly from $f(x,0) = 0$; for $\frac{\partial^{k+m} f}{\partial x^k \partial y^m}$ with odd $m$, the symmetry of $f$ yields the result; for even $m$, use that all derivatives are harmonic to move two $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ to $x$-derivatives until $m = 0$), or you use the identity theorem for harmonic functions (if two such coincide on a nonempty open set, they coincide on the domain)

Comment: with the continuation by reflection.

Comment: @user117146 Dan is always good for an answer, but I think using complex analysis is certainly the easier approach.  It's interesting to see it worked out just on reals.